# Text file sorting

Tags: bash, ubuntu, text, scripting

I just have this simple text file on my Ubuntu.

```
Clark Moon 9
Mary Apples 13
Poto Chicken 10
Coco Juice 9
Zoe Pineapple 4
Barbara Juice 6
Mark Apples 12
```

I'm trying to figure out how can I sort the text file and show only on the output names starting with "C" using sort, or grep. Anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
grep ^C file | sort
```